# on('change') not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my code which is working only one cycle of select all and deselect all. it works fine if I change the syntax to `.change` instead of `.on('change')`. Even `.change` works upto 1.8.3 version of jquery but not after that.

```
<div id="mainframe" align="center">
  <div align="left"><strong>Select All CheckBox Demo.</strong></div>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" class="table">
    <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectall"/></th>
    <th>Programming Language</th>
    <th>Rating</th>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="1"/></td>
      <td>PHP</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="2"/></td>
      <td>JSP</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="3"/></td>
      <td>ASP</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

```
$("#selectall").on('change',function () {
  if($(this).is(":checked")){
    $('.case').attr('checked',true);
  }else{
    $('.case').attr('checked',false);
  }
});
```

### [Pen](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/mgaLk)

Comment: If calling `.change` works fine but calling `.on("change", ...` doesn't, why not go with what works? I'm confused.

Comment: There's no difference between `.change()` and `.on('change', ...)` so I think something else must be going on.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle.net example showing the issue?

Comment: I want the reason why is it not working as expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Issue is with the way `attr` is used. Simplify it using `prop` instead.

```
$(function(){
    $("#selectall").on('change',function () {
        $('.case').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4NWC/)**

*Update based on your question in comment*

Version 1.3.2 of jquery does not support `on` as well as `prop`. This is a very old version where `attr` itself probably handles specific attribute value (for element `attribute`) or boolean value (for element `property`)  to add/remove attribute value (in case of  attributes of this kind (`checked`, `selected`...)) or set or unset element property based on the type of value specified. Later version of jquery introduced `prop` for setting the element property and `attr` to set the element attribute. Probably this is the reason. Also note that `on` is not supported in 1.3.2 version of jquery.

Comment: Nice workaround. Do you have (a link to) background information about the issue?

Comment: Wait - how would this have anything to do with the (admittedly suspicious) deal with `.change()` vs. `.on()` ?

Comment: The difference between `.attr()` and `.prop()`: http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here but this still doesn't explain why `.change` works while `.on('change'` doesn't.

Comment: According to OP it does, but he's probably mistaken.

Comment: Just a quick note: the native javascript "checked" property is only present in IE8+, according to this MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533556(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: PSL please use jquery upto 1.8.3 it works with that...but dont know why change doesnot work in latest version of jquery

Comment: @susheel It probably is due to the internal implementation in jquery which translated boolean value in attr to add / remove attribute in version 1.3.2. version later to that has introduced `prop` to separate out this feature. Also note that 1.3.2 does not support `on` besides `prop`

Comment: may be you are right. yeah i knew that on works after 1.7 some version. anyways your solution is simpler. Thanks. I was just curious to know why this is behaving strangely.

Comment: i was clear in my question that on worked on first cycle that means on is working. i Just changed versions and played around to get to know the issue..

Comment: @susheel if you are using attr you should use attr a mentioned in the other answer and to remove `removeAttr` to remove the attribute.

Comment: yeah saw that. now i am totally clear with the issue. and your solution is simple as gem :)

Answer (score 6):

You need to use either

```
$('.case').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

or

```
$('.case').prop('checked', true);
```

Also, you can do this in one line of code:

```
$(function(){
    $("#selectall").on('change',function () {
        $('.case').prop('checked', $(this).is(":checked"));
    });
});
```

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BWWph/